# Problems with renaming columns via variables in R

Tags: r

I'm having issues with a specific problem I have a dataset of a ton of matrices that all have `V1` as their column names, essentially NULL. I'm trying to write a loop to replace all of these with column names from a list but I'm running into some issues.

To break this down to the most simple form, this code isn't functioning as I'd expect it to.

```
nameofmatrix <- paste('column_', i, sep = "")
colnames(eval(as.name(nameofmatrix))) <- c("test")
```

I would expect this to take the value of `column_1` for example, and replace (in the 2nd line) with "test" as the column name.

I tried to break this down smaller, for example, if I run `print(eval(as.name(nameofmatrix))` I get the object's column/rows printed as expected and if I run `print(colnames(eval(as.name(nameofmatrix)))` I'm getting NULL as expected for the column header (since it was set as V1).

I've even tried to manually type in the column name, such as `colnames(column_1) <- c("test)` and this successfully works to rename the column. But once this variable is put in the text's place as shown above, it does not work the same. I'm having difficulties finding a solution on how to rename several matrix columns after they have been created with this method. Does anyone have any advice or suggestions?

Note, the error I'm receiving on trying to run this is

```
Error in eval([as.name](nameofmatrix)) <- \`vtmp\` :  could not find function "eval<-"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could return the values of the objects in a list with `get` (if there are multiple objects use `mget`, then rename the objects in the `list` and update those objects in the global env with `list2env`

```
list2env(lapply(mget(nameofmatrix), function(x) {colnames(x) <- newnames
             x}), .GlobalEnv)
```

---

It can also be done with `assign`

```
data(mtcars)
nameofobject <- 'mtcars'
assign(nameofobject, `colnames<-`(get(nameofobject), 
     c('mpg1', names(mtcars)[-1])))
```

Now, check the `names` of 'mtcars'

```
names(mtcars)[1]
#[1] "mpg1"
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how to use list2env with multiple columns? @akrun

Comment: @wolfeyes90 In the `colnames(x)` change it to the index where you want to change i.e. if you want to change the columns 1 to 5 and 8 `colnames(x)[c(1:5, 8)] <- yournewvectorofcolumnnames` in that order